# Help with applying chain rule to transformed variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation, chain-rule, change-of-variable

Given the linear homogeneous PDE

$$
y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0
$$

and the transformation

$$
u = y\exp(\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds)
$$

I need to show

$$
u'' + r(x)u = 0
$$

where

$$
r = q - \frac{p'}{2} - \frac{p^2}{4}
$$

I am trying to show this by calculating $y'$ and $y''$ via $u$ and plugging them into the first equation to get the second equation.

I use the fact that $y' = \frac{dy}{du} \frac{du}{dx}$ and $y''$ = $\frac{d^{2}u}{dx^2}(\frac{dx}{du})^2 + \frac{dy}{du} \frac{d^{2}u}{dx^2}$

And this leads me to

$$
y' = \frac{pu}{2\exp(\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds)}
$$

and

$$
y'' = \frac{p^{2}u}{4\exp(\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds)}
$$

Transforming my equation into this (by plugging in $\frac{p^{2}u}{4}$ for $u''$):

$$
u'' + \frac{p^{2}u}{2} + qu = 0
$$

However, this is not the correct equation I am trying to show.

Can someone tell me where I made a mistake in my calculations? I suspect it involves my chain rule application.

Comment: I think the use of the chain rule is wrong. You seem to assume that $$y(x) = y(u(x))$$ or something similar. But actually this is not the case, since $y$ depends also explicitly on the $x$ variable through $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0.$$
$$
u = y\exp(\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds)\Rightarrow y = \displaystyle ue^{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds}=uv,
$$
where $v=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{x} p(s) ds$. Observe that $v'=-\frac{1}{2}pv$
and $v^{''}=-\frac{1}{2}p'v+\frac{1}{4}p^2v=(-\frac{1}{2}p'+\frac{1}{4}p^2)v$.

Since $y=uv$, differentiating we get $y'=u'v+uv'=(u'-\frac{1}{2}pu)v$ and $y^{''}=u{''}v+2u'v'+uv^{''}=(u{''}-\frac{1}{2}p'u-\frac{1}{2}pu')v-\frac{1}{2}p(u'-\frac{1}{2}pu)v=[u^{''}-\frac{1}{2}p'u-\frac{1}{2}pu'+\frac{1}{4}p^2u]v$.
Now substituting $y,y'$ and $y^{''}$ into the equation $$y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$$
we get the desired transformed equation
$$
u'' + \big(q-\frac{1}{2}p'-\frac{1}{4}p^2\bigg)u = 0.$$

Comment: Perfect, it makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $$P(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^x p(y) dy.$$ We evaluate the derivatives in the following order:

$$ \partial_x u = \partial_x y e^P + y e^P\frac{1}{2}p,
$$
as well as 
$$ \partial_x^2 u = \underbrace{\partial_x^2 y e^P + 2\partial_xy e^P\frac{1}{2}p}_{-ye^P q} + y e^P \Big( \frac{1}{4}p^2 + \frac{1}{2}p' \Big).
$$
So that substituting $u =  y e^P$on the right hand-side you find the required identity.